# Clarification on random variable probelm

Tags: probability

Suppose that X is a random variable that takes values in the set:
$${1, 2, 3, 4, 5}$$

$$ P(X = 1) = P(X = 2) = P(X = 3) = P(X = 4) = P(X = 5) = 1/5$$

What is the exact value of P(X ≥ 4)?

**$Answer: P(X ≥ 4) = P(X + 4) + P(X + 5) = 2/5$**

**Why is it P(X ≥ 4) = P(X + 4) + P(X + 5) and not  P(X ≥ 4) = P(X = 4) + P(X = 5)?**

**How do I calculate P(X+4) and P(X+5)?**

Comment: The $+$ instead of $=$ inside parentheses must be a typo. (Plus and equal are on the same key on many keyboards.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $P(X \ge 4) = P(X = 4) + P(X = 5) = \frac 2 5$. $P(X+4)$ and $P(X+5)$ do not make sense because $X+4$ and $X+5$ are not events. Are those typos?

Comment: I took the answer straight from the answer sheet of a study guide. Now, I can only assume those are.

Answer (score 1):

So $P(X \geq 4)$ is equivalent to asking the question: "What is the probability of the number I randomly pick out of the set being greater than or equal to $4$".

The only numbers the set contains which satisfy this criteria are $4$ and $5$; therefore, we can say that the probability of picking a number greater than or equal to $4$ is the same as the probability of picking either a $4$ or a $5$. Or, mathematically written:

$$P(X \geq 4) = P(X = 4) + P(X = 5)$$

Calculating $P(X = 4)$ and $P(X = 5)$ has been done for you, they are both equal to $1/5$. In order to calculate them from scratch, more information about how numbers are chosen would be required.

Comment: i edited my question that clarifies my first question a bit more. Basically I am wondering why is it $P(X + 4) + P(X + 5)$? Is it different from $P(X = 4) + P(X = 5)$